# Variable doesn't cross the endlocal barrier in my script or a some mistake in the syntax inside the macro definition

Tags: batch-file

I written the following macro, I expect that the macro returns the raw of the table to the bottom referring the host name of the pc that execute the script, but it doesn't work.
It seems that there is some mistake in the syntax inside the definition of the macro.
In fact with the @echo on will be returned:

```
E:\BATCH\prova_token>(
set "par.!I!=!scriptPath!"
 set /a "I+=1"
)
!par.1! eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," not expected.

E:\BATCH\prova_token>echo
ECHO active.
```

Is there anyone can help me?

```
@echo on

:: Define LF as a Line Feed (newline) string
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove

::define a newline with line continuation
:: set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^" this is an old style and more complex \n definition
:: Next is the modern style \n definition
(set \n=^^^
%=EMPTY=%
)

set HOSTN=%COMPUTERNAME%

for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /nlbc:":: Begin Host-Pos list " "%~f0"') do set /a "beginHPL=%%N"
for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /nlbc:":: End Host-Pos list " "%~f0"') do set /a "endHPL=%%N"

set @{selectPos}=for %%. in (1 2) do if %%.==2 (for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (%\n%
    set /a "I=1"%\n%
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%1 in ("!args: =%%~L!") do (%\n%
        set "par.!I!=!%%~1!"%\n%
        set /a "I+=1"%\n%
      )%\n%
      %= Inizio della vera macro =%%\n%
      set /a "count=!par.1!+1"%\n%
      for /F "usebackq skip=!par.1! eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %%M IN (%~f0) DO (%\n%
        if %%M == !par.3! (%\n%
            endlocal^& (%\n%
                set pos.1=%%~M%\n%
                set pos.2=%%~N%\n%
                set pos.3=%%~O%\n%
                set pos.4=%%~P%\n%
                break%\n%
                )%\n%
            )%\n%
        set /a "count+=1"%\n%
    )%\n%
    %= Fine macro =%%\n%
)) else setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& set args=
%@{selectPos}% beginHPL endHPL HOSTN scriptPath
echo %pos.1% %pos.2% %pos.3% %pos.4%

:ESCI
exit /b 1000

:: Begin Host-Pos list {
;Values in the first token must be unique!!!
PRM014BBIBL04,BIBLIOTECA01,192.168.14.55,02220195
WIN030XELETT10,COMUNE01,192.168.30.101,02220168
PRM021ASPEU01,DIGIPASS01,192.168.21.142,02220917
; questa è una riga di commento e viene ignorata
:: End Host-Pos list }
```

Comment: Please provide some debugging information, and explain to us the intended task, including input and expected output. Perhaps we could offer solutions which do not require all of that convoluted 'macro' code.

Comment: The `!par.1! ... not expected.` is the key, you can't use delayedExpansion (neither %%FOR-params)  inside FOR options. Therefore it's not possible to skip a variable number of lines inside a macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endlocal ^& set "POS=%P%" %\n%` can not work, because percent expansion does not work inside a macro, as the macro itself is already expanded by a percent expansion.

Use a FOR block instead.

```
for /F %%V in ("!P!") do ( %\n%
  endlocal %\n%
  set "POS=%%V" %\n%
) %\n%
```

Btw. Your comment style:

```
if 1==2 ( comment )  %\n%
```

It works, but the comments are part of the macro.
The common style in macros
is:

```
%= comment =% %\n%
```

It allows also special characters in the comment and the comment itself is removed in the definition phase of the macro.

**After your edit:**

This could be a reasonable macro

```
@echo off

(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)

::define a newline with line continuation
:: Next is the modern style \n definition
(set \n=^^^
%=EMPTY=%
)

set "HOSTN=WIN030XELETT10"

set @{selezionaPOS}=for %%. in (1 2) do if %%.==2 (for %%L in ("!LF!") DO ( %\n%
    %= Fetching arguments =% %\n%
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%1 in ("!args!") do ( %\n%
        set "par.host=%%~1" %\n%
        set "par.listname=%%~2" %\n%
    )%\n%
%=DEBUG=%       set "par." %\n%
    %= Search for par.host in the list =% %\n%
    set "inside_list=0" %\n%
    set "found_result=" %\n%
    for /F "usebackq eol=; tokens=1,* delims=," %%1 IN ("%~f0") DO ( %\n%
        if "%%1" == ":: Begin !par.listname! {" ( %\n%
             set /a inside_list+=1 %\n%
        ) %\n%
        if "%%1" == ":: End !par.listname! }" ( %\n%
             set /a inside_list+=1 %\n%
        ) %\n%
    if !inside_list! == 1 ( %\n%
           if "!par.host!" == "%%1" ( %\n%
             set "found_result=%%1,%%2" %\n%
           ) %\n%
        ) %\n%
    ) %\n%
   FOR /F %%V in (""!found_result!"") do ( %\n%
      endlocal %\n%
      set "result=%%~V" %\n%
   ) %\n%
)) else setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& set args=

echo Test Macro

%@{selezionaPOS}% "%HOSTN%" "Host-Pos list"
echo Host record found: %result%

:ESCI
exit /b 1000

:: Begin Host-Pos list {
PRM014BBIBL04,BIBLIOTECA01,192.168.14.55,02220195
WIN030XELETT10,COMUNE01,192.168.30.101,02220168
PRM021ASPEU01,DIGIPASS01,192.168.21.142,02220917
; questa è una riga di commento e viene ignorata
:: End Host-Pos list }
```

Output:

> Test Macro
> par.host=WIN030XELETT10
> par.listname=Host-Pos list
> Host record found: WIN030XELETT10,COMUNE01,192.168.30.101,02220168

To split the result and assign it, replace the *result block*

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%1 in ("!found_result!,") do ( %\n%
      endlocal %\n%
      set "hostname=%%~1" %\n%
      set "posName=%%~2" %\n%
      set "posIP=%%~3" %\n%
      set "posID=%%~4" %\n%
) %\n%
```

The extra `,` is only for the case that `found_result` is empty

Comment: I've modified the scrypt with the "FOR block" but still doesn't work!

Comment: @AndreaRossetti The main problem is that you doesn't test anything before posting. Your macro does not even start, because of a syntax error, your variables  par.1, par.2, par.3 are empty, so you never get a result in P to return,, btw. your macro can't return anything because it exits before, ... The endlocal is your last problem, please debug first

Comment: You're absolutely right Jeb, I recycled a macro I made about 1 year ago I adapted it for this other script, but I didn't quite remember how it worked, now your comment made me remember how it works and I will make further adjustments, sorry for your trouble and thanks!

Comment: I've updated the description of this question because the problem isn't the crossing  of the endlocal barrier, but probably an error in the sintax inside the definition of the macro, but I'm actually not able to solve the problem.

Comment: OK! The Jeb solution work well, but now I need the macro, instead of just returning the selected row, to assign each comma-separated value, respectively from left to right, to the following variables: hostName posName posIP posID and make it cross the endlocal barrier.

Comment: @AndreaRossetti Easy, it's already prepared. Change the delim to a colon in `For /F  %%V in ("!found_result!") ...`. I add the necessary code

Comment: You are a batch wizard!!! :-)